# SSL connection between eDirectory and OpenLDAP

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openldap, novell, edirectory

I use a State Machine Driver to connect our eDirectory (Source) to a OpenLDAP Directory (Destination).
Without SSL everything is fine...but only for testing.

Now i need to use SSL.
I activated use-ssl (Driver Configuration -> Driver Parameters) and give the path to a keystore.
I add a self-signed-certificate of the OpenLDAP-Server to the keystore.

After restarting the driver i get (servername replaced by xxxx):

```
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
16:12:15 FFFFFFFFFAA5D700 Drvrs: eDir-OpenLDAP PT:eDir-OpenLDAP: Schema.Schema() - LDAPException: Unable to connect to server xxxx:636 (91) Connect Error
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

I used /opt/novell/eDirectory/lib/nds-modules/jre/lib/security/cacerts as keystore.

What could i try next to get the SSL-connection running?

Thank you for reading this question!

Comment: `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused` tends to be related to a server that's not listening on the address/port used by the client. Generally nothing to do with SSL. I'd check the configuration for port confusion between `LDAPS` and `LDAP+STARTTLS`.

Comment: I tried port 389 and 636. It makes no difference. I found the option "Use Mutual AuthenticationDescription of global configuration value.". After aktivating this ine i get the error: Schema.Schema() - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing key name (alias)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved.
Port 636 was closed on the destination server.

Thank you for the hint Bruno.